# django url regular expressions capture invalid url

Tags: regex, django, url

I want to understand how to create urls / regular expressions to capture and redirect to views those patterns that do not match any defined pattern.

I have a pattern in the url for the project where I am looking for waitlist.
I that does not match I want a to direct it to a project view, which I was assuming would be
caught by the second url below

```
 url(r'^waitlist/', include('waitlist.urls')),
 url(r'^.*$', views.my_default_2),
```

If the user does include the url for waitlist, then it should pass to the app url for a match
and if no match pass through to the wild card, the second line.

```
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')         
    url(r'^.*$', views.my_default),
```

Is this the correct way to capture invalid/ incorrect url input through the project and the app?

Comment: from reading i assume that `if [ inside waitlist/ ? ... (page not found, or view exit)] then you need to call my_default view` is it?

Answer (score 0):

For project you can override 404 view
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

Answer (score 0):

for default django raise exception when none found. but you can customize this for your need

You can use default page not found view

Follow this

*project/waitlist/urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from waitlist import views

urlpatterns = patterns('waitlist.views',
url(r'^$', 'index', name='index'), 
)
handler404 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_page_not_found_view'
```

*project/waitlist/views.py*

> defaults.page_not_found(request, template_name='404.html')

For reference how defaults.page_not_found works see this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/views/#django.views.defaults.page_not_found)